# Intersection point with a moving shpere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I would like to find the intersection point (first contact point) of two circles ($A$ and $B$) of different radii ($R_a$ and $R_b$) moving at constant velocities ($V_a$ and $V_b$), starting from an initial position $X_a$ and $X_b$ on two-dimensional space.

Assume we can move to a reference frame in which one of the circle is at rest. The center of the other ball is parametrized by $r'_a(t)=X'_a-V'_a\cdot t$, where $X'_a$ and $V'a$  are the initial speed and velocities of circle A in B's reference system.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Try finding the time when the square of the distance between the centers is the same as the square of the sum of the radii.

Comment: This was my first attempt - however, this assumes that at collision the vector from the intersection point $z$ to the first center is parallel to the vector from $z$ to the second center. This doesn't seem to be always the case.

Comment: How can't that be the case? At collision the circles are tangent and their radii are aligned with the tangency point.